How do I create a clear, shiny, and transparent material for my CD jewel case model in cycles?
I'm trying to achieve a realistic jewel case-look material with my model. I would like to know if this is possible through Cycles in Blender 3D 4.1. This is the effect I want to achieve: 
here's the .blend file: 

Put the Roughness at 0, the IOR around 1.5 and the Transmission at 1 and you're almost good. Also don't keep a completely white environment otherwise your object won't have anything to reflect or you won't see anything through it:


Additionally I would set the max bounces for Glossy and Transmission to at least 16 (and the Total Bounces as well as they have to be the same or more than the individual bounces for them to be effective) under Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces to make sure there are no unwanted dark parts inside the case. By the way, for more realism I would not set the Roughness to 0 but very low. And for transparent polystyrene (which jewel cases are mostly made of) there's usually an IOR of 1.55 given in some lists. But these are just details which will not really be very obvious.

@a_murt12 Oh, I see you are working in EEVEE, not Cycles... then forget the Max Bounces settings. But I would recommend you set the Base Color to fully white instead of light grey.

Yes the file is set to Eevee but he's asking for Cycles

Yeah, my reading comprehension is a bit lacking in the mornings when I did not have at least 5 coffees :)

yeah i accidently left  the engine to EVEE instead cycles when exchanging files so sorry about that. nevertheless thank you for the detailed explanation! i found that a roughness around 0.025 works fine enough for inserts and booklets to be see through the case.
